# Inject into Databinding Adapter with Dagger 2

Tags: android, data-binding, picasso, dagger-2, android-binding-adapter

I am using Android Databinding adapter and it says, it have to be static. So I am trying to make it non static and inject my classes into it with Dagger by following [this tutorial](https://philio.me/using-android-data-binding-adapters-with-dagger-2/). Although I can use my `Picasso` instance which is provided by dagger normally in app, it says `Picasso cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method`.

I add @Inject annotation to my binding adapter constructor but still get same error

```
public class ImageBindingAdapter {

    private final Picasso picasso;

    @Inject
    public ImageBindingAdapter(Picasso picasso) {
        this.picasso = picasso;
    }

    @BindingAdapter("android:src")
    public void loadImage(ImageView view, String url) {
        picasso.load(url).fit().into(view);
    }
}
```

I thought the problem might be relevant about a `component` issue and changed my approach and followed [this link](https://github.com/IlyaPavlovskii/Android-MVVM-Wrapper/wiki/Dagger-2---DataBinding) and use `subcomponent`. But this time dagger can not generate subcomponent and I can not set it like in the example

```
// Build dagger binding subcomponent and set it like default databinding component 
        DataBindingUtil.setDefaultComponent(sApplicationComponent
                .daggerBindingComponentBuilder()
                .build());
```

How can I inject my custom classes into binding adapter with Dagger, any help is appreciated

Here is my dagger classes, it is pretty same from tutorial that I mentioned above

**ImageBindingAdapter Class**

```
public class ImageBindingAdapter {

    private final Picasso picasso;

    @Inject
    public ImageBindingAdapter(Picasso picasso) {
        this.picasso = picasso;
    }

    @BindingAdapter("android:src")
    public void loadImage(ImageView view, String url) {
        picasso.load(url).fit().into(view);
    }
}
```

**BindingModule class**

```
@Module
public class BindingModule {

    @Provides 
    @DataBinding
    ImageBindingAdapter provideImageBindingAdapter(Picasso picasso) {
        return new ImageBindingAdapter(picasso);
    }
}
```

**BindingComponent class**

```
@DataBinding
@Component(dependencies = AppComponent.class, modules = BindingModule.class)
public interface BindingComponent extends DataBindingComponent {

}
```

**AppComponent class**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class, AppModule.class, ...})
public interface AppComponent extends AndroidInjector<MyApp> {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        Builder application(Application application);
        AppComponent build();

    }

    @Override
    void inject(MyApp instance);
}
```

**AppModule class**

```
@Module
public class AppModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    Picasso picasso(Application application, OkHttp3Downloader okHttp3Downloader) {
        return new Picasso.Builder(app.getApplicationContext())
                .downloader(okHttp3Downloader)
                .indicatorsEnabled(true)
                .build();
    }

     ....

}
```

**Application class**

```
    public class MyApp extends DaggerApplication {

        @Override
        protected AndroidInjector<MyApp> applicationInjector() {

           AppComponent appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder().application(this).build();

            appComponent.inject(this);

            BindingComponent bindingComponent = DaggerBindingComponent.builder()
                .appComponent(appComponent)
                .build();
             DataBindingUtil.setDefaultComponent(bindingComponent);

            return appComponent;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your `dagger` component and module stuff? As error said, you didn't marked any constructor of Picassso with `@Provides` annotation - as it's not possible as I understand, because it's external class for you. So you need define function inside class, marked with `@Module`, that should looks like `@Provides public Picasso providePicasso() {TODO cretae picasso instance}`.

Comment: @ConstOrVar check my edit pls, shared dagger classes too

Comment: Try add `Picasso getPicasso();` in `AppComponent` interface

Comment: @ConstOrVar, it worked but why? I have never need to add a class that provided by module in appComponent, my app component just contains builder

Comment: As I understand, you can set as component dependency any interface - so dagger can use methods from that interface to resolve other dependencies. If your component dependency have no public methods (except builder), it's not safe for dagger to use internal methods (because it's part of realization and can be changed at any time - public methods should be treated as contract).

Comment: I understood, in the first link, author says "In order to satisfy the dependency for Picasso in BindingModule, it also has to be exposed by the AppComponent (this step would not be required if using a sub-component)". Which is the best approach, using subcomponent or this? I tried to implement subcomponent by following second link but not be successful @ConstOrVar

Comment: If you use `subcomponent` approach, it allows root component share it's stuff with subcomponents. With `dependent component` approach - all component should have public methods for each instance they supply. Which of these approaches to use - it depends on many factors. If you want your components don't depend on each other (hardly) or sometimes you don't have access to modify other components - it'll be better to use `dependent component` approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ConstOrVar, could you post it as answer so I can mark it as a correct answer and last if possible can you share subcomponent implementation of this case?

Comment: Ok. I'll try to share with you subcomponent approach later today

Comment: "it says, it have to be static" who is "it"?

Comment: @MarianPaździoch error's itself, "A BindingAdapter in in is not static and requires an object to use, retrieved from the DataBindingComponent. If you don't use an inflation method taking a DataBindingComponent, use DataBindingUtil.setDefaultComponent or make all BindingAdapter methods static."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As error said, dagger could not resolve `Picasso` dependency. In your case, the problem is that differenct dagger components can use directly only those dependencies, that interface marked with `@Component` annotation declared using methods. To allow `AppComponent` share `Picasso` with `BindingComponent` you need modify app component like that:

```
@Singleton 
@Component(modules = {AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class, AppModule.class, ...}) 
public interface AppComponent extends AndroidInjector<MyApp> { 
    ...
    Picasso getPicasso();
}
```

After that dagger can properly resolve `Picasso` dependency and error should disappear.

Answer (score 0):

@BindingAdapter should be `public static void`, see [Binding adapters docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters#java).

Comment: I know, but I do not want to make it static